# RoR: How to create a wrapper for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to integrate solr search engine with an RoR app. There is a controller in the app `product_search_controller` which uses the primitive search methods. I want to create a new controller for plugging in the solr serach engine.

I am planning to create a wrapper around `product_search_controller` to do that. What is the best way of creating the wrapper. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although there's a huge variety of options, I'd suggest the conventional way of using `concerns`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Rails 4 generates `concerns` directories by default. Basically, you'll just need to define all of the functionality inside your `concerns/searchable.rb` (example name) and `include Searchable` inside your controller